# Count shaded and unshaded rectangles in an grid image with noise

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am trying to count all the shaded and un-shaded rectangles in this grid using python. I tried contour detection in OpenCV and was not able to achieve this. I also tried the hough line transform and detected the lines in the image, but I am not able to figure out how to proceed further. Is there a better way of doing it? Can someone suggest a way to proceed?

[image: recognize_image]

Comment: Err, there's an ellipse there too - what's that for?

Answer (score 1):

As your image looks very clean, I would

- threshold the image to select white regions: gray regions and black lines will be black
- use findContours() to count white blobs
- do another threshold to select black lines. Only black lines will be black, everything else white
- XOR the two images: this way you should have the gray regions
- use findContours() to count the gray blobs

EDIT:
The ellipse cuts some rectangles and this will affect your count. If you want to remove it, the thresholds are not enough (both the ellipse and the rectangle lines are black). A possible way to do it:

- With Hough Lines you can detect the lines,
- draw in a new image the vertical and horizontal lines (ignore diagonal lines as they may be part od the ellipse)
- with boolean operations (and, xor or or) between the thresholded images and the lines image you should be able to keep only the lines and remove the ellipse